# How to calculate average of data

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am working on a Bluetooth based app, where i am getting 18 values string data, I am getting 50 datas like that. No i want to calculate average of it.

```js
The data i am getting is like ..
"123,120,34,56,23,22,62,72,14,32,54,74,44,44,21,43,41,54"
"125,120,34,56,23,22,62,72,14,32,54,74,44,44,21,43,41,54"
"123,120,34,56,23,22,62,72,14,32,54,74,44,44,21,43,41,54" 
"124,118,35,56,23,22,62,72,14,32,54,74,44,44,21,43,41,54" 
and to 50....
```

Now for these 50 data values I want to get a average.

```js
Like for average of [1] = 123, [2]=120 etc
```

So how can I do this in android/java

Comment: well, what have you tried ?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see how this question is related to Firebase, but assuming that you want to save the average value of those numbers that you get through your Bluetooth sensor in the Firebase Realtime Database, for example, please see the next approach. Let's assume you have those numbers as a list:

```
List<String> lines = Arrays.asList(
        "123,120,34,56,23,22,62,72,14,32,54,74,44,44,21,43,41,54",
        "125,120,34,56,23,22,62,72,14,32,54,74,44,44,21,43,41,54",
        "123,120,34,56,23,22,62,72,14,32,54,74,44,44,21,43,41,54",
        "124,118,35,56,23,22,62,72,14,32,54,74,44,44,21,43,41,54"
);
```

Now, to get all the numbers and calculate the average, please use the following lines of code:

```
double sum = 0;
int count = 0;
for (String line : lines) {
    String[] numbers = line.split(",");
    for (String number : numbers) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(number);
        count++;
    }
}
double average = sum/count;
System.out.println("average: " + average);
```

Things to notice, I have split each line using "," (comma) and stored the results into an array of String elements. Then I have iterated each array to get the corresponding numbers. I have also added a counter variable to count each iteration, assuming that those lines might **not** all have the same number of numbers. In the end, I have simply logged the result in the logcat:

```
average: 51.861111111111114
```

To write this value into Firebase Realtime Database, you can try this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference avarageRef = rootRef.child("bluetoothData").child("avarage");
avarageRef.setValue(average);
```

The result in the database will be:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- bluetoothData
        |
        --- average: 51.861111111111114
```

Comment: i want avg of each element in that 18 values, like 123,120,80,90,75... etc

Comment: @user9648620 check my answer

Comment: @user9648620 I'm not sure I understand. You need an average for each "line" and in the end to have the average for all lines?

Comment: Lets suppose you have 18 columns and 50 rows, no I want average of individual number. so result will be 1 row and 18 columns. so if there are 50 values like 132,24,53,23,89... i want average of each number in that set

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not aware of an "average of the individual number". [Average refers to the arithmetic mean, the sum of the numbers divided by how many numbers are being averaged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average). So you cannot apply that to a single number. Can please be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a map and using streams collect the average for each set that you have.

```
    String r0 = "123,120,34,56,23,22,62,72,14,32,54,74,44,44,21,43,41,54";
    String r1 = "125,120,34,56,23,22,62,72,14,32,54,74,44,44,21,43,41,54";
    String r2 = "125,120,34,56,23,22,62,72,14,32,54,74,44,44,21,43,41,54";

    //here just add all the other strings you have received r3,r4,....r50
    List<String> data = Arrays.asList(r0, r1, r2);
    
    Map<String, Double> averages = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    data.forEach(k -> {
        List<String> s = Arrays.asList(k.split(","));
        OptionalDouble avg = s.stream().mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).average();
        avg.ifPresent(avgVal -> {
            System.out.println(avgVal);
            averages.put(k, avgVal);
        });
    });
    System.out.println(averages);
```

In the end your map will hold for each string that you provided which contained 18 elements as value the average value of those 18 elements.

Comment: Yeah that would also work, but does anyone here know how OP got his avarage results. The ones he mentioned: [1] = 123, [2]=120 etc.
Because I don't

Comment: @IntoVoid he explained in another comment, he wants a different average for each string. He has 50 of those strings each containing 18 elements

Comment: thanks but this cal. the avg of 18 values, I'll explain in simple terms, imagine there are 18 rows and 50 columns and now you want to get average of that, the result will be in 18 rows and 1 col. @Boug

Comment: @user9648620 then this solution will also work. If you add 18 ro, r1, ...r18 then in the end you will have 18 averages calculated on the 50 numbers each contained. Try it

Comment: @user9648620 in your question however each string contains 18 elements not 50. How can those be considered rows? Those are columns as you describe. So you have 18 columns in your question not 50